# Update intermediate result

Tags: postgresql

**EDIT**
As requested a little background of what I want to achieve. I have a table that I want to query but I don't want to change the table itself. Next the result of the `SELECT` query (what I called the 'intermediate table') needs to be cleaned a bit. For example certain cells of certain rows need to be swapped and some strings need to be trimmed. Of course this could all be done as postprocessing in, e.g., Python, but I was hoping to do all of this with one query statement.

---

Being new to Postgresql I want to update the intermediate table that results from a `SELECT` statement. So I basically want to edit the resulting table from a `SELECT` statement in one query. I'd like to prevent having to store the intermediate result.

I've tried the following 'with clause':

```
with result as (
    select
        a
    from
        b
)
update result as r
set
    a = 'd'
```

...but that results in `ERROR:  relation "result" does not exist`, while the following does work:

```
with result as (
    select
        a
    from
        b
)
select
    *
from
    result
```

As I said, I'm new to Postgresql so it is entirely possible that I'm using the wrong approach.

Comment: It is hard to understand what output you want from the query ... please explain the desired output .

Comment: You can only update a `table` in a `UPDATE` query. `WITH` is used to create a  Common Table Expressions/CTEs ans can be considered only as a temporary table.

Comment: So WITH is not the way to go, but is there an alternative?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. You say you want to "edit" an intermediate table, but why? You do not want to change the underlying table? What will you do with the updated intermediate table? Try to explain your desired functionality without assuming a certain solution, it is possible that your functionality could be achieved in a completely different way.

Comment: Thanks, @Patrick I've added a little more background of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of the transformations you want to perform, you might be able to munge it into the `SELECT`, which would let you get away with a single query:

```
WITH foo AS (SELECT lower(name), freq, cumfreq, rank, vec FROM names WHERE name LIKE 'G%')
SELECT ... FROM foo WHERE ...
```

Or, for more or less unlimited manipulation options, you could create a temp table that will disappear at the end of the current transaction. That doesn't get the job done in a single query, but it does get it all done on the SQL server, which might still be worthwhile.

```
db=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
db=# CREATE TEMP TABLE foo ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT * FROM names WHERE name LIKE 'G%';
SELECT 4677
db=# SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 5;
   name   | freq  | cumfreq | rank |          vec
----------+-------+---------+------+-----------------------
 GREEN    | 0.183 |  11.403 |   35 | 'KRN':1 'green':1
 GONZALEZ | 0.166 |  11.915 |   38 | 'KNSL':1 'gonzalez':1
 GRAY     | 0.106 |  15.921 |   69 | 'KR':1 'gray':1
 GONZALES | 0.087 |  18.318 |   94 | 'KNSL':1 'gonzales':1
 GRIFFIN  | 0.084 |  18.659 |   98 | 'KRFN':1 'griffin':1
(5 rows)

db=# UPDATE foo SET name = lower(name);
UPDATE 4677
db=# SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 5;
  name  | freq  | cumfreq | rank  |         vec
--------+-------+---------+-------+---------------------
 grube  | 0.002 |  67.691 |  7333 | 'KRP':1 'grube':1
 gasper | 0.001 |  69.999 |  9027 | 'KSPR':1 'gasper':1
 gori   | 0.000 |  81.360 | 28946 | 'KR':1 'gori':1
 goeltz | 0.000 |  85.471 | 47269 | 'KLTS':1 'goeltz':1
 gani   | 0.000 |  86.202 | 51743 | 'KN':1 'gani':1
(5 rows)

db=# COMMIT;
COMMIT
db=# SELECT * FROM foo;
ERROR:  relation "foo" does not exist
```